# ID collision on CANOpen SDO

Tags: can, esp32, bus, canopen

I am working on a remote control module to control my heating boiler remotely. The boiler uses CANOpen 125k.

My module transmits periodically SDO requests to read temperatures and other parameters. Sometimes it results in a bus error.

I have been debuging a lot on hardware level, but after sniffing it turned to be a logic problem.

It seems like every ~10 seconds each possible CAN SDO Frame is sent over the bus (all IDs from 0x601 to 0x67F). It looks like a scan or something like this. Looks like IDENTITY query (0x40 0x1018 2...).

Is there any way to prevent this scan from happening or avoid frame ID collision?

I am not using any library at this moment, just pumping raw CAN frames. Maybe I am missing something that tells the other side to avoid using specific ID?

Comment: Sounds like one or several nodes aren't CANopen compliant. Truly serious vendors take their products through a 3rd party test house (CAN in Automation), after which their products are "ceritified CANopen". You can search and see if your products are certified here: https://www.can-cia.org/services/test-center/conformance-testing/tested-devices/.

Comment: Thanks. This particular vendor does not exist in the database. Anyway, what is the purpose of iterating through SDOs if there is LSS mechanism?

Comment: I can't say that I know what's going on in this case, but it can be handle to scan through a node to learn what items it supports and contains. Not something I'd expect to happen in actual production code though.